# Remove the "uah"

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I wrote a parser that should parse exchange rates but there is a final touch.
Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk02hYi-HCGXbHdPuek-VJRu_8qsUVg%3A1587054998453&ei=lomYXvaSG7zAmwWP_LHQBA&q=%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80+%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0&oq=&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQARgBMgcIIxDqAhAnMgcIIxDqAhAnMgcIIxDqAhAnMgcIIxDqAhAnMgcIIxDqAhAnMgcIIxDqAhAnMgcIIxDqAhAnMgcIIxDqAhAnMgcIIxDqAhAnMgcIIxDqAhAnOgQIABBHSgkIFxIFMTAtMjRKCAgYEgQxMC0yUPFtWPFtYKt8aAFwAngAgAEAiAEAkgEAmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdperABCg&sclient=psy-ab'
HEADERS = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36', 'accept': '*/*'}


def get_html(url, params=None):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return r

def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_="VgAgW")
    currency = []
    for item in items:
        currency.append({
            'uah': item.find('span', class_='SwHCTb').get_text(strip=True),

        })
        print(f"'Now the course:' + {currency}")
    return currency


def parse():
    html = get_html(URL)

    if html.status_code == 200:
        get_content(html.text)
    else:
        print('Error')


parse()
```

I don’t know how to remove this: [{'uah':}]
Here is what comes out:

```
'Now the course:' + [{'uah': '27,22'}]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Why do you put your items into a dict if you don't want to print them as a dict? Also, describe how it *should* be printed, and how that should look when you have more than one currency.

Comment: I think what you want is to change currency in your printf to currency[0]['uah']. But the above comment by Charles is right. Why are you making a dict for every occurence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Currency is a list `currency = []` so when you print list it's always prints like this `[]`.
2. Currency is a list of dicts `{'uah': ...}` so when you print dict it's always prints like this `{key: value}`.
3. Looks like you need to `print(f"Now the course: {currency[0]['uah']}")` where `[0]` is the first element of list, which is dict, and then gets value of that first dict by it's key `'uah'`.

You can add an additional variable `course` to make it easier to access the value:

```py
course = item.find('span', class_='SwHCTb').get_text(strip=True)
currency.append({'uah': course})
print(f"Now the course: {course}")
```